# What is the maximum number of input geometries for the ArcGIS Server REST geometry service Relation operation?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-rest-api, http-post

I'm receiving an error from ArcGIS Server on a large-ish(≈3800 geometries) collection of geometries on the [relation http post operation](http://sampleserver5.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer/relation):

```json
{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Error executing relation",
  "details": []
 }
}
```

The ArcGIS Log has the error as: `Software caused connection abort: socket write error` (actual stack pasted below).

Smaller collections of several hundred complete successfully. Is there hard-limit? And if so, what is it?

---

```xml
<Msg time="2016-03-08T16:53:42,932" type="DEBUG" code="9999" source="Server" process="3672" thread="1" methodName="" machine="XXXXX" user="" elapsed="">
    java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:157)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.esri.arcgis.discovery.ejb.util.EJBBase.handleRequestBase(EJBBase.java:451)
    at com.esri.arcgis.discovery.ejb.impl.GenericServerBean.handleRequest(GenericServerBean.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor105.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:162)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:144)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:162)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:144)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:122)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:174)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:136)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.doEjbObject_BUSINESS_METHOD(EjbRequestHandler.java:238)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbRequestHandler.processRequest(EjbRequestHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.processEjbRequest(EjbDaemon.java:196)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbDaemon.service(EjbDaemon.java:149)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:71)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.KeepAliveServer$Session.service(KeepAliveServer.java:213)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.KeepAliveServer.service(KeepAliveServer.java:233)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ejbd.EjbServer.service(EjbServer.java:66)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ServicePool$2.run(ServicePool.java:91)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.ServicePool$3.run(ServicePool.java:120)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1876)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.writeByte(ObjectOutputStream.java:1914)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1575)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:350)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.marshalValue(UnicastRef.java:293)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:152)
    ... 34 more
</Msg>
```

Comment: This is dependent on many factors, your browser, your hardware, your definition of "suffer" https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/limits_for_graphics.html

Comment: I think you can remove browser from that list--since I can reproduce the issue without a browser.  The exception is on the server and not on the client.  There are plenty of server resources are available--I don't even see an increase of anything (CPU/RAM) when making the request.  Just the geometry service crashing and restarting.